# Literal equivalent to "fed up"

Tags: phrase-requests

How can I express in an informal way that I've eaten, and ready to continue what I was doing before, akin to saying that my phone's charged up, or a petrol tank has been filled up?

For example:

> User A: Are you ready?
>
> User B [who's just had lunch]: Yep, I'm ready. I'm [fed up] and ready to continue.

Comment: There could be many ways to say it. It would be nicer if you could explain why you need "informal" way. Your question might be regarded "too broad" or opinion-based, I am afraid.

Comment: I'm finished or I'm full?

Answer (score 1):

Consider **"I'm full"** (mentioned by deadrat in comments), or **"I'm full up"**.

Another suggestion would be **["I'm stuffed"](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stuffed)**:

> completely full, so that you cannot eat any more

If an idiom is OK, consider **"My eyes are bigger than my stomach"**:

> used for saying that someone has taken more food than they can eat

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-s-eyes-are-bigger-than-their-stomach-belly#someone-s-eyes-are-bigger-than-their-stomach-belly__1))

(The idiom doesn't syntactically fit the example sentence, but if the sentence is not writ in stone, it could work.)

Comment: "Fully charged" -- that one I've never heard. "Loaded" would mean very drunk to me. Edit: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=loaded

Answer (score 1):

In your example,

> I'm fed and ready to continue

works well. You can use that if you start to say "fed up" and change your mind at the last second...if you wait a split second too late,

> I'm fed uh...and ready to continue

also works.